# How to multiply array([1,1,1]) with array([2,3,4]) to get array[[2,3,4], [2,3,4], [2,3,4]]?

Tags: python, numpy

Is there any way in numpy to multiply array([1,1,1]) with array([2,3,4]) to get array[[2,3,4], [2,3,4], [2,3,4]]?

Without using any recursion, loop, reduce, filters, comprehension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple broadcasting:

```
In [158]: a=np.array([1,1,1]); b=np.array([2,3,4])
In [159]: a[:,None]*b
Out[159]: 
array([[2, 3, 4],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [2, 3, 4]])
```

That's a (3,1) with a (3,) => (3,3)

Or

```
In [161]: np.outer(a,b)
Out[161]: 
array([[2, 3, 4],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [2, 3, 4]])
```